# Can I use the ALL operator to test that all values of a "group" exist in another query/set? If so, how?

Tags: sql, sql-server

- I have this database for a CS/database-theory homework question for a hypothetical movie store company:

  - For those who might be unfamiliar with the concept, a *movie store* is a retail location where patrons can film productions on VHS tape, or this newfangled format called "DVD".

    - <sub>Who knows, maybe some time in the distant, far-off, future we might be able to view movies directly over the Internet?</sub>
  - The DDL and sample data is below.
- I need to write a query that will show all movies that are available in **all three** Chicago stores: (`WI01`, `WI02`, and `WI03`).

  - By looking at the raw data below ourselves, we can see that only these 3 `movieId` values (`D00001`, `D00006`, and `D00007`) have `movie_store` rows for *every* `store` located in Chicago.

```
CREATE TABLE movie (
    movieId varchar(6)   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    title   nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE store (
    storeId varchar(4)   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    city    nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE movie_store (
    movieid varchar(6) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES movie ( movieId ),
    storeid varchar(4) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES store ( storeId ),

    PRIMARY KEY ( movieId, storeId )
);

GO

INSERT INTO movie ( movieId, title )
VALUES
('D00001', N'True Lies'),
('D00002', N'Predator'),
('D00003', N'Last Action Hero'),
('D00004', N'Red Heat'),
('D00005', N'Conan 1'),
('D00006', N'Conan 2'),
('D00007', N'Red Sonja');

INSERT INTO store ( storeId, city ) VALUES
('WI01', N'Chicago'),
('WI02', N'Chicago'),
('WI03', N'Chicago'),
('IL01', N'Atlanta'),
('IL02', N'Nashville');

INSERT INTO movie_store ( movieId, storeId ) VALUES
-- True Lies:
('D00001', 'WI01'),
('D00001', 'WI02'),
('D00001', 'WI03'),
-- 'Predator:
('D00002', 'IL01'),
('D00002', 'IL02'),
-- Last Action Hero:
('D00003', 'WI01'),
-- Red Heat:
('D00004', 'WI01'),
('D00004', 'WI02'),
('D00004', 'IL02'),
-- Conan 1:
('D00005', 'WI01'),
('D00005', 'WI02'),
-- Conan 2:
('D00006', 'WI01'),
('D00006', 'WI02'),
('D00006', 'WI03'),
-- Red Sonja:
('D00007', 'WI01'),
('D00007', 'WI02'),
('D00007', 'WI03');
```

- During my problem-solving research I found a [site](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sql-server/sql-all-operator) explaining the `ALL` operator.

  - My query is getting unique `storeIds` for Chicago.
  - It is then trying to get the movie `title` with a `storeId` record for each one of the Chicago locations.

```
WITH chicagoStores AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        storeId
    FROM
        store 
    WHERE
        city = 'Chicago'
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    m.title
FROM
    movie AS m
    INNER JOIN movie_store AS y ON m.movieid = y.movieid
    INNER JOIN store       AS s ON y.storeid = s.storeid
WHERE
    s.storeId = ALL( SELECT storeId FROM chicagoStores )
```

But my query returns zero rows (and no errors), am I misunderstanding the `ALL` operator?

Comment: Please don't give your tables `ALLUPPERCASENAMES`, it's a pain to read.

Comment: It is a homework question. This is not production. It is just a few simple tables with one query that I am unable to figure out. I've gone as far as I can on my own, so I came here.

Comment: I was just about to say, because "movie stores" haven't really existed in the US for... at least a decade now.

Comment: "show all movies that are available in each of the three Chicago stores" - your requirement is not clearly defined: are you after the set of movies such that every individual movie is concurrently available in **all** stores in chicago, or just the set of movies that are available in **at least 1** chicago store?

Comment: Looking for movies that are in all 3 Chicago stores.  True Lies, Conan 2, & Red Sonja

Comment: So _Last Action Hero_ and _Conan 1_ should be excluded (which are only available at _some_, not _all_ Chicago stores)? If so, then you should rephrase it as "that are available **at all** Chicago stores", not "available in each Chicago store", because that's more ambiguous and open to interpretation.

Comment: Perhaps to you, but not everyone interprets the same words the same way you think they do - this is how misunderstandings happen.

Comment: You misunderstood the `ALL` operator. Your query is exactly what is stated in that site example 1

Comment: Hopefully your   class mentioned a technique for relational division.  This is what you need here.

Comment: He did say it would involve relational algebra, but we should consider using subqueries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select city,title,count(*)
from 
store
inner join movie_store
on store.storeid = movie_store.storeid
inner join movie
on movie_store.movieid = movie.movieid
where city = 'Chicago'
group by city,title
having count(*) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears I had the wrong idea about ALL. I realized I could write my query this way to get the movies that appeared in all Chicago locations. Thanks for your help everyone.

```
with stores as (
    select count(distinct(storeid)) as count_store
    from store 
    where city = 'Chicago'
),
     count_movies as (
    select z.title, count(*) as count
    from movie z
    join movie_store y on (z.movieid = y.movieid)
    join store x on (y.storeid = x.storeid)
    where x.city = 'Chicago'
    group by z.title
    having count(*) = (select count_store from stores)
)
select title from count_movies
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without a window and without mentioning `chicago` 2 times

```
select m.title,
       s.city
from   store s
  inner join movie_store ms on s.storeid = ms.storeid
  inner join movie m on ms.movieid = m.movieid
  cross apply (select count(1) numbers from store s2 where s2.city = s.city group by s2.city) c
where  s.city = 'Chicago'
group by m.title, s.city, c.numbers
having  count(s.storeid) = c.numbers
```

Try it yourself at this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=750642146845b46bc8105335538006cf)

Answer (score 0):

- [The `x = ALL y` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/all-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) isn't what you want.

  - It sounds like you want an operator to test that "all values in x are also in y", aka an "`ALL IN`" operator.

    - [Unfortunately `ALL IN` does not exist in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490961/sql-all-in-clause), despite its obvious utility.
  - The `x = ALL y` operator actually tests to see if all values in `y` (the right-hand-side *single-column table-expression*) equal the single scalar value `x`.

    - This functionality is not relevant to the problem as we don't need to test that some result-list equals some single row's column.
    - The other operators aren't of much use either (e.g. `x != ALL y` or `x < ALL y`).
- While there is no `ALL IN` operator in SQL, [the concept exists in relational-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) where it's known as **relational division**.

  - Conceptually (and if it existed in SQL) then `x DIVIDE y ON y.foo = x.foo` would by like `GROUP BY x.foo HAVING x.foo ALL IN ( SELECT foo FROM y ) UNGROUP` (of course, `UNGROUP` *isn't a thing either*).
  - [It's a common PITA to implement relational-division in SQL](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

---

From a high-level, the problem can be broken-down into 4 steps:

1. Get the set of `storeId` values for Stores in Chicago.

   - i.e. `SELECT storeId FROM store WHERE city = 'Chicago'`
2. Separately, get the set of `movieId` values for all movies in *those* stores.

   - i.e. `SELECT * FROM movie_store AS ms INNER JOIN chicagoStores AS cs ON ms.storeId = cs.storeId`
3. Then group/partition the `chicagoMovies` set by their separate `movieId` values.
4. Then filter out those groups/partitions where each partition's set of `storeId` values does not equal the `chicagoStores` set.

But here's the hard-part: SQL does not offer a way to evalaute a predicate condition *for each partition* in a `GROUP BY` query.

SQL is more like Relational Calculus, where you describe *what you want*, as opposed to Relational Algebra, where you describe *how you want it done*. Linq is an example of a relational-algebra query language in comparison to SQL.

In Linq (for in-memory objects, *not* Entity Framework), you would do it like this:

```cs
HashSet<StoreId> chicagoStores = Stores
    .Where( s => s.City == "Chicago" )
    .Select( s => s.StoreId )
    .ToHashSet();

MovieStores
    .GroupBy( ms => ms.StoreId )
    .Where( grp => grp.All( ms => chicagoStores.Contains( ms.StoreId ) ) )
    .SelectMany( grp => grp )
    .Select( ms => ms.Movie )
```

So I went for a completely different approach in SQL:

1. Get the set of `storeId` values for Stores in Chicago:

   ```sql
   WITH chicagoStores AS (
       SELECT
           storeId
       FROM
           store
        WHERE
           city = 'Chicago'
   )

   StoreId
   -------
   WI01
   WI02
   WI03
   ```
2. Get the set of `movieId` values for movies that are in *at least 1* Chicago store.

   ```sql
   WITH anyChicagoStoreMovieIds AS (
       SELECT DISTINCT
           ms.movieId
       FROM
           movie_store AS ms
           INNER JOIN chicagoStores AS cs ON
               cs.storeId = ms.storeId
   )

   movieId
   -------
   D00001
   D00003
   D00004
   D00005
   D00006
   D00007
   ```

   - Alternatively, the set of *all* `movieId` values in `movie` could be used, but doing that would make Step 3 potentially much slower.
3. Generate the `CROSS APPLY` of Step 1 and Step 2, which generates the Cartesian Product of every Chicagoan `storeId` with every `movieId`.

   - Hence why restricting it to a the smaller upper-bound set from Step 2 makes sense, as there's no point including `movieId` values that don't appear in *any* Chicago store.

   ```sql
   WITH whatIfEveryChicagoStoreHadEveryMovie AS (
       SELECT
           m.movieId,
           cs.movieId
       FROM
           chicagoStores AS cs
           CROSS APPLY anyChicagoStoreMovieIds AS m
   )

   movieId  storeId
   -------
   D00001   WI01
   D00001   WI02
   D00001   WI03
   D00003   WI01
   D00003   WI02
   D00003   WI03
   D00004   WI01
   D00004   WI02
   D00004   WI03
   D00005   WI01
   D00005   WI02
   D00005   WI03
   D00006   WI01
   D00006   WI02
   D00006   WI03
   D00007   WI01
   D00007   WI02
   D00007   WI03
   ```
4. Now the hard part:

   - Consider that **if** any given Chicago `storeId` had **every** `movieId` possible, then such a row would already-exist in `movie_store`...
   - ...therefore it follows that if we then **subtract** *actual* rows in `movie_store` from Step 3's result, then we'll be left with the set of `( movieId, storeId )` tuples that *don't exist* but which would *need* to exist in order for *every* Chicago `storeId` to have that movie.

   ```sql
   WITH chicagoanMoviesNotAvailableAtEveryChicagoanStore AS (
       SELECT
           w.movieId,
           w.storeId
       FROM
           whatIfEveryChicagoStoreHadEveryMovie AS w
           LEFT OUTER JOIN movie_store AS ms ON
               w.movieId = ms.movieId
               AND
               w.storeId = ms.storeId
       WHERE
           ms.storeId IS NULL
   )

   movieId  storeId
   ----------------
   D00003   WI02
   D00003   WI03
   D00004   WI03
   D00005   WI03
   ```
5. Then it's just a matter of subtracting `chicagoanMoviesNotAvailableAtEveryChicagoanStore` from `anyChicagoStoreMovieIds` (from Step 3), which gives us the set of `movieId` values that **are** available at every Chicagoan `storeId`:

   ```sql
   WITH moviesNotIn_moviesNotInAtLeast1ChicagoStore AS (
       SELECT movieId FROM anyChicagoStoreMovieIds
       EXCEPT
       SELECT movieId FROM moviesNotInAtLeast1ChicagoStore
   )

   movieId  storeId
   ----------------
   D00003   WI02
   D00003   WI03
   D00004   WI03
   D00005   WI03
   ```
6. Which can then be `INNER JOIN`ed with `movie` to get their `title` information, etc:

   ```sql
    SELECT
        m.movieId,
        m.title
    FROM
        moviesNotIn_moviesNotInAtLeast1ChicagoStore AS ffs
        INNER JOIN movie AS m ON
            ffs.movieId = m.movieId;

   movieId  title
   ----------------
   D00001   'True Lies'
   D00006   'Conan 2'
   D00007   'Red Sonja'
   ```

Thus giving the full final query:

```sql
WITH
chicagoStores AS (
    SELECT storeId FROM store WHERE city = 'Chicago'
),
anyChicagoStoreMovieIds AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ms.movieId
    FROM
        movie_store AS ms
        INNER JOIN chicagoStores AS cs ON cs.storeId = ms.storeId
),
expectedMovieStores AS (
  SELECT
    m.movieId,
    cs.storeId
  FROM
    chicagoStores AS cs
    CROSS JOIN anyChicagoStoreMovieIds AS m
),
moviesNotInAtLeast1ChicagoStore AS (
  SELECT
    e.*
  FROM
    expectedMovieStores AS e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN movie_store AS ms ON
      e.movieId = ms.movieId
      AND
      e.storeId = ms.storeId
  WHERE
    ms.storeId IS NULL
),
moviesNotIn_moviesNotInAtLeast1ChicagoStore AS (
    SELECT
        movieId
    FROM
        anyChicagoStoreMovieIds
         
    EXCEPT
         
    SELECT
        movieId
    FROM
        moviesNotInAtLeast1ChicagoStore
)
SELECT
    m.movieId,
    m.title
FROM
    moviesNotIn_moviesNotInAtLeast1ChicagoStore AS ffs
    INNER JOIN movie AS m ON
        ffs.movieId = m.movieId;
```

The CTEs that are only used once can be inlined to shorten the query somewhat:

```sql
WITH
chicagoStores AS (
    SELECT storeId FROM store WHERE city = 'Chicago'
),
anyChicagoStoreMovieIds AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ms.movieId
    FROM
        movie_store AS ms
        INNER JOIN chicagoStores AS cs ON cs.storeId = ms.storeId
),
expectedMovieStores AS (
    SELECT
        m.movieId,
        cs.storeId
    FROM
        chicagoStores AS cs
        CROSS JOIN anyChicagoStoreMovieIds AS m
)
SELECT
    m.movieId,
    m.title
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            movieId
        FROM
            anyChicagoStoreMovieIds

        EXCEPT

        SELECT
            e.movieId
        FROM
            expectedMovieStores AS e
            LEFT OUTER JOIN movie_store AS ms ON
                e.movieId = ms.movieId
                AND
                e.storeId = ms.storeId
        WHERE
            ms.storeId IS NULL
    ) AS ffs
    INNER JOIN movie AS m ON
        ffs.movieId = m.movieId;
```

...which is stioll rather long and complex for what's described as a CS/SQL homework - this took me over 2 hours to figure out because it was driving me mad.

Answer (score 0):

After plugging-away for a bit more, [and reading this article on Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), I think I've found a *much shorter* query [compared to my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71435025/159145):

```sql
SELECT
    m.movieId,
    m.title
FROM
    movie AS m
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT m.movieId, s.storeId FROM store       AS s WHERE city = 'Chicago'
        EXCEPT
        SELECT r.movieId, r.storeId FROM movie_store AS r WHERE r.movieId = m.movieId
    );
```

---

The explanation below is based on this slightly longer-form version which is otherwise *identical* in its relational-calculus:

```sql
WITH chicagoStores AS (
    SELECT storeId FROM store WHERE city = 'Chicago'
)
SELECT
    m.movieId,
    m.title
FROM
    movie AS m
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        -- Generate rows we'd *expect to exist* if a given `m.movieId` is present in every Chicago storeId:
        SELECT
            m.movieId,
            s.storeId
        FROM
            chicagoStores AS s

        -- Then subtract the `movie_store` rows that *actually exist* for this m.movieId:
        EXCEPT

        SELECT
            a.movieId,
            a.storeId
        FROM
            movie_store AS a
        WHERE
            a.movieId = m.movieId
    );
```

- Generate the same `chicagoStores` set.
- Then, filter `movieId` values in `movie` (in `WHERE`) by...

  - Generate a set of *hypothetical* `movieId, storeId` tuples (for that specific `movieId` value) from `chicagoStores`...
  - ...and subtract that from the *actual* rows in `movie_store` (using `EXCEPT`)...

    - This is the same thing as `whatIfEveryChicagoStoreHadEveryMovie` from my original answer, but computed on a a per-row basis, instead of (conceptually) generating the `( movies X stores ) EXCEPT movie_store` Cartesian Product subtraction all-at-once.

      - ...with the implication that this *might* require *less maximum total memory* on the database-server, but that's entirely dependent on the execution-plan and DB engine.
  - ...and if there are any *hypothetical* rows remaining (using `EXISTS`) after the `EXCEPT` then it means that the `movieId` is *not* available in *all* Chicagoan stores.
  - So if we invert the predicate (`NOT EXISTS`) then that means we can test to see if a specific `movieId` value **is available** in *all* Chicagoan stores.

    - But **be careful** as it would also have false-posities when/if the `chicagoStores` collection was empty (as `NOT EXISTS ( x EXCEPT y )` is always `true` when `x` is empty, even if `y` is also empty.

      - As a workaround, change `FROM movie` to `FROM anyChicagoStoreMovieIds` (where `anyChicagoStoreMovieIds` is defined in my other answer).